# Saving dynamically created list box in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, local-storage

I have made a Google map with a list of possible mapped locations in a "source" list box. You can select however many you want and push a button and they go to the next list box. Once you push the "map locations" button they all get mapped. 
I have tried, and failed, to get the desired locations that are listed dynamically to be saved and recalled using local storage so when a user returns to the page then their last locations are still there. This is important for those using an ipad and possibly other tablets. 
Can someone please help with getting the dynamically created options saved in the list box? I have read many articles regarding local storage but this seems to be a unique situation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>     

        <style type='text/css'>
            #map-canvas { width:940px; height:625px; }
            .layer-wizard-search-label { font-family: sans-serif };

        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
            var map;
            var layer_0;
            var destSelect;
            var filter;

            function initialize() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.724544549099676, -100.43701171875), 
                    scaleControl: true,
                    zoom: 7, //zoom
                    zoomControl: true,
                            zoomControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT},
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //the map style
            });

            layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                map: map
            });
            ///Storage
            filter = document.getElementById("filter");
            destSelect = document.getElementById("destSelect");

            if (localStorage.locations)
                destSelect.value = localStorage.locations;

            }

            function saveChoice() {
                localStorage.locations=destSelect.value;    
                console.log + localStorage.locations;
            }
            ///
            function changeMap_0() {
                var query={
                    select: "'geometry'",
                    from: "1xDlCWWj4WMCadzaua5bBss3UNLprGCnsS3H4vt0"
                },
                values=[],
                options=document.getElementById('destSelect').options;

                if(!options.length){
                    //no options added, remove the layer
                    //and leave the function
                    layer_0.setMap(null);
                    return;
                } 

                //collect the values  
                for(var i =0;i<options.length;++i){
                    values.push(options[i].value.replace(/'/g, "\\'"));
                }
                //create where-clause
                query.where="'Well Name' IN('"+values.join("','")+"')";

                //set the options  
                layer_0.setOptions({query:query,map:map}); 
            }
            function listboxMoveacross(sourceID, destID) {
                var src = document.getElementById(sourceID);
                var dest = document.getElementById(destID);

                for(var count=0; count < src.options.length; count++) {

                    if(src.options[count].selected == true) {
                            var option = src.options[count];
                            var newOption = document.createElement("option");
                            newOption.value = option.value;
                            newOption.text = option.text;
                            newOption.selected = true;
                            try {
                                    dest.add(newOption, null); //Standard
                                    src.remove(count, null);
                            }catch(error) {
                                    dest.add(newOption); // IE only
                                    src.remove(count);
                            }
                            count--;
                    }
                }
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)
        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div> 
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select id="filter" multiple="1">
                            <option value="101 FEDERAL  21X-24">101 FEDERAL  21X-24</option>
                            <option value="13 MILE SWD  1">13 MILE SWD  1</option>
                            <option value="2-BRENDEN  9-33 1-M">2-BRENDEN  9-33 1-M</option>
                            <option value="20002 JV-P AGATE     1">20002 JV-P AGATE     1</option>
                            <option value="20002 JV-P AGATE     2">20002 JV-P AGATE     2</option>
                        </select>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button onclick="listboxMoveacross('filter', 'destSelect');">&gt;&gt;</button>  <br>
                        <button onclick="listboxMoveacross('destSelect', 'filter');">&lt;&lt;</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="destSelect" size="10" multiple="" onchange="saveChoice()">
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button id="mapbutton" onClick="changeMap_0(map);">Map Locations</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing happen when you move location from left to right side. `onchange` event is not triggered when `dest.add(newOption, null);` finishes. You have to do that 'manually' dispatching event or maybe with unselecting and selecting the same location to trigger change event. Now `saveChoice()` is not called.

Answer (score 2):

You have double instances of `listboxMoveacross()` - why? As @Anto Jurković comments, nothing will happend on `onchange`. Instead

1. save all items from `destSelect` each time it is modified
2. on `initialize()`, load the list, add them to `destSelect` and remove them from `filter`.

saving to storage, call that in your `listboxMoveacross()` :

```
function saveToStorage() {
    var destSelect=document.getElementById("destSelect");
    for (var i=0;i<destSelect.length;i++) {
        localStorage.setItem('option_'+i, destSelect.options[i].text);
    }
}
```

retrieving the stored options in `initalize()` and remove stored options from `filter` :

```
function loadFromStorage() {
    var destSelect=document.getElementById("destSelect");
    var filter = document.getElementById("filter");
    var filterOut = [];
    for (var i=0;i<filter.length;i++) {
        var storedOption=localStorage.getItem('option_'+i);
        if (storedOption != 'null' && storedOption != null) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = storedOption;
            option.innerHTML = storedOption;
            destSelect.appendChild(option);
            filterOut.push(option);
        }
    }
    //remove stored options from filter
    for (var i=filter.length;i>=0;i--) {
        for (var t=0;t<filterOut.length;t++) {
            if (filter.options[i]!=undefined) {
                if (filter.options[i].text.localeCompare(filterOut[t].text)==0) {
                    filter.removeChild(filter[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

see fiddle with your code above and my additions -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3AHwz/**
add some values to `destSelect`, then do a reload.

Comment: thank you. Yes, `listboxMoveacross()` was a typo. I had moved it and forgot to delete. The options saved successfully upon reload as you said, however, I had expected, at no fault to you, that I could push the "Map Locations" button after the reload to map those options. Is that still possible? And also a way to delete the saved data?

Comment: @user1871068, I do not totally understand the first, "push map locations button..", call `changeMap_0()` after `loadFromStorage()`?? but yes - I forgot, you should clear the localStorage each time it is changed before saving the content of `destSelect` - simply `localStorage.clear();`

Comment: The goal would be for a user to navigate away from the page, then upon returning, having those same locations on the map-canvas. So, in this instance, when the user returns they will see those locations in the list box and ideally just have to push the "Map Locations" button to get those markers back.

Comment: your fiddle worked great for saving the items in the listbox but any idea how to get those on the map? I have tried a few things in trying to get the `onClick="changeMap_0(map);"` ti fire the saved option items and nothing works.